# (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str) python

Tags: python, json, api, вконтакте

Сам код

```
        version2 = 5.103
        searcher_owner_ID = input(Fore.GREEN + 'Write id: ')
        searcher_GET = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.getMentions',
                                    params={
                                        'owner_id': searcher_owner_ID,
                                        'access_token': token2,
                                        'v': version2
                                    }
                                    )
        searcher_result = searcher_GET.json()['response']['items']['post_type']['text']
        print(searcher_result)
```

Json

```
{"response":{"count":115,"items":[{"id":706911,"from_id":-48392922,"to_id":-48392922,"date":1582992711,"post_id":704796,"post_type":"reply","text":"[id367316021|Вадим], ты выиграл  Напиши в лс группы по ссылке https:\/\/vk.me\/rushbru \"победил\", чтобы забрать 10 монет\n\n Качай приложение SkinSwipe и вводи свой промокод","marked_as_ads":0,"attachments"
```

Python выдаёт ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Вот в этой строке:

```
searcher_result = searcher_GET.json()['response']['items']['post_type']['text']
```

Вечно у меня с этим проблемы :( , кто сможет объяснить, как это устроено и как это пофиксить?

Буду очень сильно благодарен)

Comment: `...["items"]` это список, а не словарь.

Answer (score -1):

**Чел ответ находится прямо в ошибке.**

> Индекс списка должен быть числом или срезом, не строкой.

Скорее всего ошибка здесь:
searcher_result = searcher_GET.json()['response']['items']['post_type']['text']
Ты неправильно обращаешься к элементам списка, это тебе не словарь! Порочитай про списки, словари и кортежи и узнай что такое индекс и срез, и узнай как обращаться к определенным элементам.
**Вот те ссылочка:**
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

Comment: Почитал, понял что надо мне собрать все данные т.е. [:]. Но и тут проблема, как я смогу присвоить ему это значение, если мне надо, чтобы это уместилось в одну переменную searcher_result? Можешь привести пример, если не сложно?